# How to set up a shortcut for 2 finger trackpad scrolling?

Tags: keyboard, trackpad, keybindings, macos, multi-touch

I would like to set up a keyboard shortcut (say Command + Left Arrow and command + Right Arrow) to do the same thing as 2 finger Left/Right scrolling.

Or, map the mousewheel to this input.

How to do this?

Use case:
I am running parallels and am using a software that works with 2 finger scrolling. But it does not work with the mousewheel. Shift + mousewheel should be the same input as Left/Right 2 finger trackpad scrolling.

So, I want to map shift + mousewheel or a keyboard shortcut to 2 finger trackpad scrolling.